COMSOL multipysics - thermal stress for cubeSat in low earth orbit eigenvalue slover error
I'm using COMSOL version 6.2 for my simulation work. I'm dealing with Heat Transfer involving Radiation and Thermal Stress in solids phisics only after inserting all the constants and boundry conditions then RUN
Errors
(Change the shift in the eginvectors solver) I change it from left to right then this message shown (No eignpairs solution detected)
Kindly find attached viedos link for the whole set up
1-(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lGbREBDvv6Y2VKa9txvqPPeqzupfw1KQ/view?usp=sharing)
2-(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SlYr9M4VqY5dvl5guqVtSfCkBl-2z6Zd/view?usp=sharing)
for any farther information please contact me.
Aboayman27xXx@gmail.com

Have you checked thoroughly for typos in the boundary conditions and constants?

Mr. Mike
Thanks a lot for your coopration, yes all the boundry conditions are defined and verified by the physics (heat transfer using orbital thermal loads).
and I calculate all the constants and they verified by my advasior.
Kindly check the videos above.
thanks a lot

In looking at the first video it appears that earth albedo source is set to none.  The radiation sources considered when I worked on vehicle  thermal control in orbit for Apollo, many eons ago, were direct solar solar radiation, earth albedo  (solar reflected radiation) , and direct radiation (long wavelength) from the earth and the time varying orientation of your object relative to these sources. Never used zero earth albedo.
